# insert array in multidimensional array

Tags: php

I have an array that looks something like this.

```
Array
(
    [consultant] => Array
        (
            [John Smith] => Array
                (
                    [General] => Array
                        (
                            [PCA] => 0
                            [NCA] => 0
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

How do I append a array to `PCA` in place of the 0

to look like this.

```
Array
(
    [consultant] => Array
        (
            [John Smith] => Array
                (
                    [General] => Array
                        (
                            [PCA] => Array
                                (
                                    [Motor Block] => 0
                                )
                            [NCA] => 0
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d9b20040517e557fe93fdf1208079a619dcc213b

Comment: would this help? http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivearrayiterator.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just find the proper path from the array structure and assign the array to this key:

```
$array['consultant']['John Smith']['General']['PCA'] = array('Motor Block'=>0);
```

If you however want to change the value `0` on key `PCA` to this array no matter how deep this value is, use `array_walk_recursive`:

```
function change(&$v,$k){
    if($v == 0 && $k == 'PCA'){
        $v = array('Motor Block'=>0);
    }
}
array_walk_recursive($array,'change');
```

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3af10b9c88dcbc1af474a743a6c4a7cf5687f3ba

Comment: I would think the OP already knows how to do that, no? I was thinking more of a recursive function that would loop till the res is not an array.

Comment: @Grimbode, Yes thats what I had in mind. Sorry if my question was not clear. Thanks Grimbode. I have updated the question to try and make it more understandable.

Comment: @Grimbode OK, thanks for remark, I updated my answer with working solution